# How could I use PDF.js with web2py?

Tags: pdf, web2py, pdf.js

with web2py, if I have a blob field defined as follows:

Field('pdf','upload', uploadfield='pdf_file'),
  Field('pdf_file', 'blob')

How could I use PDF.js (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) to display the file?

Comment: Something like Example 33 at http://www.web2py.com/init/default/examples ?

Comment: I do not want to download the PDF file. I want to display it as embed in the web page.